# SMS API integration in django

Tags: python-3.x, django-rest-framework

I'm using DJANGO and i want to integrate an SMS API into my DJANGO app. Can anyone help in knowing where (in which file) to write the code for integration and also the code to integrate SMS API?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your requirements. If you have a complex sms sending system, it would be better to create a new django app for this system and write a class (maybe model) for processing sms sending. I'd advice you to keep models fat, but views skinny. You can execute sms sending from signals, celery, views so on, according to your needed of course.
Regarding to the integrating code, take a look on the sms provider's specification. It must exists. If not, find a better provider, who cares about his clients.